# AzureB2C Custom Policies - How to redirect a user to registration page automatically if the user is not available in the directory with Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to develop a custom polices for the user Migration in Azure B2C. I don't want to push all the user details from the database to Azure B2C through Graph API, instead whenever the user tries to login, check for the record, if it is not found in B2C redirect them to sign up page. I'm using the Azure B2C custom policies starter pack.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done in a way that before attempting for login you have to read the user using the user name or email. Once you read the user, **objectId** will have value. If it is null, means the user is not present. By checking objectId exists in orchestration step you can make a sub journey like password reset to show registration or modify the login flow accomodate signup too. Following is an example for how to check user exist in AD B2C

[Check user exist in AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867036/how-to-check-user-exists-in-ad-b2c-using-custom-policy)